# How to make online map projection from DotSpatial.Plugins.WebMap same as current map projection

Tags: dotspatial

When I upload a shapefile (its projection is WGS84 UTM Zone 37N) to the map, mouse coordinates on map are in WGS84 UTM Zone 37N. When I add online map using DotSpatial.Plugins.WebMap, it changes the map projection.

Is there any way to convert online map projection to current map projection ? (in this example current map projection is WGS84 UTM Zone 37N. I attached map pictures before and after online map.

Online map before:
[image: before online map]

Online map after:
[image: after online map]